# Difference between MacBooks with Model Numbers Z1AF_101_DE_CTO and Z1AF-MRW13D/A-AAIM?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm currently looking into buying a 16" M3 Pro MacBook in Black with 18GB Ram and 1TB SSD. A shop lists this model, but with different Model Numbers and different prices. The specifications look exactly the same. So what is the difference between these two?

**Z1AF_101_DE_CTO - 3055€**
[image]

**Z1AF-MRW13D/A-AAIM - 3321€**
[image]

Comment: The only likely variants are color and keyboard language. Probably best to ask the shop. The designation "Z1AF" seems to be used a lot, but Apple model numbers tend to be something like "MRW13D/A".

Comment: CTO is "Configure to Order", but this doesn't really make sense here (at least not with the information given). Doing a web search on Z1AF_101_DE_CTO returns quite a few hits, but this could just be a network of resellers. Best to ask the vendor (maybe also why their offer is >10% cheaper than buying directly from Apple).

Comment: I already contacted the shop, but didn't receive an answer yet. Color ("Space Black" / "Schwarz") and language ("Key-ID-Deutsch" / "DE") seem to be the same. Configure to order does indeed not make sense, as you can't configure anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shop answered: These are not obscure Apple Model Numbers, but MacBooks sourced from different vendors which use different Model Numbers for the same MacBooks. There really is no technical difference.

Comment: Nice. The CTO is often used to indicate “custom to order” when someone makes a custom configuration when purchasing. Apple doesn’t stop someone from specifying a model they also make in bulk and sell under a standard model.